# Combi Instinct 199 - hot water radiator pressure

Tags: water, radiator, combi

I recently had a oopsie where I tried bleeding one of my colder radiators and I accidentally unscrewed the bleeder valve too far and it popped out. Bunch of water came out but I was able to eventually plug it up with a new bleeder valve once pressure dropped low enough. Lesson learned there.

My boiler works fine now and the pressure reads about 15 psi. Right after I plugged up my radiator, I had a "low pressure" warning pop up but it's gone now. Low pressure pops up at 10 psi I believe. 7 psi is minimum operating pressure.

Does this system automatically add water back in to re-pressurize the whole system? My one radiator is now closed still.

Comment: That depends on the details of how your system is plumbed and what valves are open/closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plumber came out and said combi 199 system I have does refill and re-pressure itself.